# Transforming a 4x3 dataframe into a 1 row dataframe

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I am working in a lab and I am triying to get the outputs of one device measuring aromatics compounds in a weird format not tidy at all but required by our lab management system software. My initial dataframe looks like this:

```
Aromatic_type           Concentration Concentration2
1     Monoaromáticos          6.52          83.65
2       Diaromáticos          6.39          49.89
3      Triaromáticos         22.36         125.62
4 Aromáticos Totales         36.82         311.48
```

and I would need it to be transformed into a 1 row dataframe like this:

```
Monoaromáticos Concentration Monoaromáticos Concentration2 Diaromáticos Concentration etc...
                        6.52                         83.65                       6.39
```

I have tried with `tidyr` and `reshape` but I guess I am still a rookie, any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I am getting your input data correctly.

Assuming that the input file looks like (perhaps the text is not quoted, but I am using quotes for simplicity):

```
"Aromatic_type" "Concentration" "Concentration2" 
"Monoaromáticos" 6.52 83.65 
"Diaromáticos" 6.39 49.89 
"Triaromáticos" 22.36 125.62 
"Aromáticos Totales" 36.82 311.48
```

Then the following code will produce the data in the wide format you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

datos <- '"Aromatic_type" "Concentration" "Concentration2"
"Monoaromáticos" 6.52 83.65
"Diaromáticos" 6.39 49.89
"Triaromáticos" 22.36 125.62
"Aromáticos Totales" 36.82 311.48'

df <- read_delim(datos, delim = " ", quote = '"')[, 1:3] 

df2 <- df %>% 
pivot_longer(
  cols = c(2:3),
  names_to = "concentracion",
  values_to = "valores"
) %>% 
unite(
  col = "medida",
  1:2,
  sep = " "
) %>% 
pivot_wider(
  names_from = medida,
  values_from = valores
)
df2
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
`Monoaromáticos… `Monoaromáticos… `Diaromáticos C… `Diaromáticos C…
<dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1             6.52             83.6             6.39             49.9
# … with 4 more variables: `Triaromáticos Concentration` <dbl>,
#   `Triaromáticos Concentration2` <dbl>, `Aromáticos Totales
#   Concentration` <dbl>, `Aromáticos Totales Concentration2` <dbl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I forgot to format the data. This worked perfectly fine, I didn't know about the pivot functions in dplyr :-)